# openx 2.8.1 "Session ID is invalid" when using XMLRPC api + ruby openx gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, xml-rpc, openx

Occasionally when accessing OpenX 2.8.1 via its XMLRPC api (using the ruby 'openx' gem), I will get this error message:

> Session ID is invalid

I cannot find anything in OpenX's forums about this, nor via some Google searching.

I am starting to suspect that it is a bug or other issue in the ruby gem itself.

Has anyone else encountered such an error, and if so, what is the fix? It *does* seem to resolve itself after running OpenX's maintenance scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In using OpenX with a JSP application, we've found that too long a period of inactivity between the application and OpenX will cause the OpenX to invalidate the session ID. Currently our application was unable to get itself a new session, our workaround has been a restart of the application.

Comment: Ack! Same behavior I've been seeing, and unfortunately, similar solution. Restarting apache for us seemed to do it too, in addition to running the maint. scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenX 2.6 my server connection would time out after about 25 minutes.   Not sure I could ever find a current reference for it, but it worked to track the connection time and simply re-establish the connection after a timeout.

```
def openx_connection
  return @connection if (@timeout && Time.now < @timeout) 
  OpenX::Services::Base.connection=nil   # clear any remaining connection
  OpenX::Services::Base.configuration = {
    'username'  => @username,
    'password'  => @password,
    'url'       => @url }
  @timeout = Time.now + 25.minutes
  @connection = OpenX::Services::Base.connection  # establish a new connection
end
```